# Quantity in the "Add to Cart Success Notification" (Opencart - Journal Theme)

Tags: javascript, php, arguments, opencart, journal

Opencart 3.0.2.0
With Journal 3.1.8 Theme

I try to show quantity of product on add to cart success notification.
Notification has no twig file.

This is my notification controller file.

I need to bring it to before $args['message'].
But i couldn't figure it out how.
I think i need to call it from common/cart?

```
<?php

use Journal3\Opencart\ModuleController;
use Journal3\Utils\Arr;

class ControllerJournal3Notification extends ModuleController {

    public function index($args) {
        $data = parent::index($args);

        $this->journal3->document->addJs(array('notification' => array(array(
            'm' => $this->module_id,
            'c' => $this->settings['cookie'],
        ))));

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Journal3\Options\Parser $parser
     * @param $index
     * @return array
     */
    protected function parseGeneralSettings($parser, $index) {
        return array(
            'classes' => array(
                'notification',
            ),
            'options' => array_merge_recursive(
                array(
                    'position' => $parser->getSetting('notificationStylePosition'),
                    'title'    => $parser->getSetting('title'),
                ),
                $parser->getJs()
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param \Journal3\Options\Parser $parser
     * @param $index
     * @return array
     */
    protected function parseItemSettings($parser, $index) {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * @param \Journal3\Options\Parser $parser
     * @param $index
     * @return array
     */
    protected function parseSubitemSettings($parser, $index) {
        return array();
    }

    public function cart($args) {
        if (!$this->journal3->settings->get('notificationStatus')) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->load->language('common/cart');

        if ($args['product_info']['image']) {
            $image = $this->model_journal3_image->resize($args['product_info']['image'], $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.width'), $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.height'), $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.resize'));
            $image2x = $this->model_journal3_image->resize($args['product_info']['image'], $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.width') * 2, $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.height') * 2, $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.resize'));
        } else {
            $image = false;
            $image2x = false;
        }

        return array(
            'className' => 'notification-cart',
            'position'  => $this->journal3->settings->get('cartNotificationStylePosition'),
            'title'     => Arr::get($args, 'product_info.name', 'product_info.option_name'),
            'image'     => $image,
            'image2x'   => $image2x,
            'message'   => $args['message'],
            'buttons'   => array(
                array(
                    'className' => 'btn btn-cart notification-view-cart',
                    'name'      => $this->language->get('button_continue_cart'),
                    'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', '', true),
                ),
                array(
                    'className' => 'btn btn-success notification-checkout',
                    'name'      => $this->language->get('text_checkout'),
                    'href'      => $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', true),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function wishlist($args) {
        if (!$this->journal3->settings->get('notificationStatus')) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($args['product_info']['image']) {
            $image = $this->model_journal3_image->resize($args['product_info']['image'], $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.width'), $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.height'), $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.resize'));
            $image2x = $this->model_journal3_image->resize($args['product_info']['image'], $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.width') * 2, $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.height') * 2, $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.resize'));
        } else {
            $image = false;
            $image2x = false;
        }

        return array(
            'className' => 'notification-wishlist',
            'position'  => $this->journal3->settings->get('wishlistNotificationStylePosition'),
            'title'     => Arr::get($args, 'product_info.name'),
            'image'     => $image,
            'image2x'   => $image2x,
            'message'   => $args['message'],
            'buttons'   => '',
        );
    }

    public function compare($args) {
        if (!$this->journal3->settings->get('notificationStatus')) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($args['product_info']['image']) {
            $image = $this->model_journal3_image->resize($args['product_info']['image'], $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.width'), $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.height'), $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.resize'));
            $image2x = $this->model_journal3_image->resize($args['product_info']['image'], $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.width') * 2, $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.height') * 2, $this->journal3->settings->get('image_dimensions_notification.resize'));
        } else {
            $image = false;
            $image2x = false;
        }

        return array(
            'className' => 'notification-compare',
            'position'  => $this->journal3->settings->get('compareNotificationStylePosition'),
            'title'     => Arr::get($args, 'product_info.name'),
            'image'     => $image,
            'image2x'   => $image2x,
            'message'   => $args['message'],
            'buttons'   => '',
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Figured it out with ajax and jawascript coding. Thank you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).